# std::thread notation when defining the threaded function

Tags: c++, multithreading

I understand the `std::thread` notation presented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) and reproduced as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>

void f1(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Thread " << n << " executing\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}

void f2(int& n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 2 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::thread t1; // t1 is not a thread
    std::thread t2(f1, n + 1); // pass by value
    std::thread t3(f2, std::ref(n)); // pass by reference
    std::thread t4(std::move(t3)); // t4 is now running f2(). t3 is no longer a thread
    t2.join();
    t4.join();
    std::cout << "Final value of n is " << n << '\n';
}
```

because the definition of `f1` and `f2` is within `main` but fail to understand

```
#ifndef THREADED_H_
#define THREADED_H_

class Threadme
{
    long count;

public:

    Threadme();

    void run(void);

    void delay(long);
};

#endif

#include "threaded.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

Threadme::Threadme() : count(0) {}

void Threadme::delay(long seconds)
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end_t = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(seconds);

    while(std::chrono::system_clock::now() < end_t)
       ;
}

void Threadme::run(void)
{
    while(count < 10)
    {
        ++count;

        std::cout << count << std::endl;

        delay(1);
    }

}

#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

#include "threaded.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    std::thread t1(&Threadme::run, Threadme());

    t1.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

specifically the expression `std::thread t1(&Threadme::run, Threadme());` as it relates to defining the threaded function `run` outside of `main`.  Why the reference `&` and why the thread `parameters` is a constructor invocation?

Comment: `&` has many meanings in C++. It doesn't just mean "reference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&Foo::mem` where `Foo` is a class type and `mem` a member (function or value) of `Foo`, is C++ notation for obtaining a pointer to a member (function or value). There exist a special syntax for invoking a member function pointer on an object, but this is usually sugared away by using `std::mem_fun`, which will turn a member function pointer into an ordinary function where the first argument has to be an object of the type the member function was taken from.

`std::thread` understands what is happening here and does exactly that: invoke `Foo::mem` on the object passed as the second argument.

A small example to reproduce this locally without actually involving `std::thread`:

```
#include <functional>

class Foo { void mem() {} };

int main() {
  Foo f;
  f.mem(); // normal invoke
  auto func = std::mem_fun(&Foo::mem);

  func(std::ref(f)); // invoke mem on f
  func(f); // invoke mem on a copy of f
  func(&f); // invoke mem on f through a pointer
}
```

Why don't we need the `mem_fun` when constructing `std::thread`? It
automatically detects those situations through an overload and does
the right thing all by itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can see a member function of `ThreadMe` as a function that accepts an implicit first parameter of type `ThreadMe*` - also known as `this`. This analogy is not 100% correct and might be shred to pieces by some language lawyer, but it serves for understanding the call you have there.

`std::thread` and many other classes/functions that accept functions and parameters for them, like e.g. `std::bind` and `std::function` accept pointers to member functions, followed by an object on which the function has to be called, or put otherwise, followed by that implicit first parameter.

So `void ThreadMe::run()` can be seen as `void run(ThreadMe&);` Then the call that bothers you is easy to understand. Consider your second example:

```
void f1(int n);
int n;
std::thread t2(f, n); //calls f in a new thread, passing n
```

now create the int just when it's needed:

```
std::thread t2(f, int()); //calls f, passing a copy of the int that has been created here...
```

with ints that might not make so much sense, but with an object it does:

```
void run(ThreadMe&);
std::thread t1(run, ThreadMe()); //conceptually the same as above
```

and since we know thet member functions are just a bit more than syntactic sugar for that implicit first argument, the call you have is still nothing else but the above:

```
void ThreadMe::run(); //implicit first argument is a ThreadMe&
std::thread t1(ThreadMe::run, ThreadMe()); //pass a copy of that newly created ThreadMe as the implicit first argument of the run method.
```

If you know lambdas, this is very similar, i.e. it passes a copy of a fresh `ThreadMe` to the thread that calls run on that copy::

```
ThreadMe threadMe;
std::thread t1([=](){ threadMe.run(); });
```

In fact, since the binding of parameters to functions that happens under the hood of `std::thread`'s constructor is somewhat unusual, I prefer using lambdas, since they explain explicitly anything the thread has to do. In this case I would not create that temporary `ThreadMe` to call the thread, I would create a nontemporary inside the thread itself:

```
std::thread t1([](){ 
  ThreadMe threadMe;
  threadMe.run(); 
});
```